# Application Insights - regex flags

Tags: regex, azure-application-insights

I made this very simple regex

```
extract("ProductCode",0,message)
```

And of course it's working but I have no idea how to make it case-insensitive. I tried to add 'i' flag like this

```
extract("productcode/i",0,message)
```

or like this

```
 extract("/productcode/i",0,message)
```

nothing works.. no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Comment: Try `extract("(?i)ProductCode",0,message)` if `ProductCode` is a constant string in the regex and you want to extract that string only, and it is parsed with a library like Python `re`, Java, .NET, PHP.

Comment: Or try `(?i:ProductCode)` as regex, according to [here](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/References/Regular-Expressions-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following syntax:

```
(?i)productcode(?-i)
```

This will make that part of your regex case insensitive. 
You can dismiss the (?-i) if you want to apply it to the whole regex.

Good luck.